# Checking If A WordPress Widget Displayed In The Current Front End

Tags: wordpress

Is there a function to check if a widget is **displayed** in the current front end?
This is necessary for pulling some styles or scripts or doing other action to the widget.

Comment: wordpress.SE has several posts on this topic, for example: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/2302/loading-scripts-only-if-a-particular-shortcode-or-widget-is-present/2304#2304

Comment: `is_active_widget()` only checks if a 'xyz' widget is active in global $wp_registered_widgets. So if you have a 'xyz' widget active in other sidebar, it always return active for the current page even there is no 'xyz' widget in the current page.

Comment: Yes... but it returns the sidebar ID if true. So if you know what sidebars are on the current front end then problem solved. So your problem runs in circles considering your other question (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13404283/get-wordpress-sidebars-fom-the-current-front-end/13407134#comment18323631_13407134). (I think this right but I'm not sure what sidebar ID is returned if several instances of the widget is active.)

Comment: Yes Calle it is circling so I think i should separated it. `is_active_widget()` returns the id of sidebar **in which** the widget is active, not to the current active sidebar in the front end. Perhaps we should know what is the current active widget id in the front end.

Comment: I took another look at the `dynamic_sidebar` function and I think I managed to pull it off. Check my answer below. I don't know why I didn't see it this morning :/

Answer (score 0):

Please see if this works by echoing the contents $GLOBALS['displayed_sidebars'] and $GLOBALS['displayed_widgets'], using print_r for example.

It must be tested after dynamic_sidebar has been executed for all sidebars that you want to include.

```
add_filter( 'dynamic_sidebar_params', function( $params ) {
    global $displayed_sidebars, $displayed_widgets;
    if( !in_array( $params[0]['id'], $displayed_sidebars ))
        $displayed_sidebars[] = $params[0]['id'];

    if( !in_array( $params[0]['widget_name'], $displayed_widgets ))
        $displayed_widgets[] = $params[0]['widget_name'];

    return $params;
});
```