# Get WordPress Sidebars Fom The Current Front End

Tags: wordpress

Is there a function to retrieve the WordPress sidebar(s) that is displayed in the current front end?

Answer (score 0):

I posted a solution that might work, here: [Checking If A WordPress Widget Displayed In The Current Front End](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13403867/checking-if-a-wordpress-widget-displayed-in-the-current-front-end#comment18327258_13403867)

<strike>dynamic_sidebar doesn't register that it's been called for that and that sidebar. Neither is there a suitable hook to do this yourself. So I'm afraid you would have to tell Wordpress for each template what sidebars are being displayed.</strike> One way to do this would be to create a wrapper function like this

```
function wrap_dynamic_sidebar( $sidebar_id )
{
    global $sidebars_in_this_template;
    $sidebars_in_this_template[] = $sidebar_id;
    return dynamic_sidebar( $sidebar_id );
}
```

And replace dynamic_sidebar with this everywhere (but I understand that it is very likely this solution will not be feasible for you).

If you want to display a list of all sidebars, you could use $wp_registered_sidebars

```
global $wp_registered_sidebars;
$sidebar_ids = array_keys( $wp_registered_sidebars );
```

Comment: Assuming we are creating plugins and replacing `dynamic_sidebar` in all templates is hard to do.

Comment: There are many scenarios like it; child themes and so on. But the lack of filter in dynamic_sidebar that passes on the sidebar ID means there  really isn't any perfect solution. It's not that we haven't found it. It _just doesn't exist_.